# Jquery: Append HTML to a variable containing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, append

I have a var containing a bunch of HTML. I want to append a link to it before appending the var to a wrapper div,eg:

```
var content = '~html generated from JSON~'
$content.append.("<a href='link'>Link</a>");
```

I've tried a few ways of doing this but I cant get it right or find any info on SO.

Do I need to 'explode' the variable before hand?

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need JQ for this. Use just plain JS like `content += "<a href='link'>Link</a>"`

Comment: what does `$content` mean here?

Comment: Did you mean this? `$(content).append("<a href='link'>Link</a>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
content += "<a href='link'>Link</a>";
```

*$content* is not the same as *content*, acutally *$content* is something you would have to declare yourself, usually when you use jQuery the $ prefix is used for variables that relate to something on the dom to which you can apply jQuery methods. So if *$content* was a domnode you can do $content.append, but not before you declare it. Your *content* variable is a string to which jQuery methods do not apply.

Answer (score 4):

You can select your generated HTML with the jQuery selector, which will parse it into actual DOM nodes. From there you can do whatever you need to with it:

```
var $content = $('~html generated from JSON~'),
    $link = $('<a href="link">Link</a>');

$content.find('span').append($link);
```